# UIButton Enable/Disable No working

Tags: ios, uibutton

`UIButton` enable not working after Xcode Update to Xcode 5.0.1.

```
self.btn.enabled = NO;
self.btn.hidden = NO;
```

Please suggest.

Comment: post your full code of uibutton.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode 5. Perhaps you ran into this due to iOS 7 or a problem in your code or xib or storyboard.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably check the following in your project :

---

### Checklist

- Make sure that the button `btn` is connected to the relevant button in the **xib** in the Interface Builder.
- Check whether the method where you put the two lines `self.btn.enabled = NO;` and  `self.btn.hidden = NO;` gets called or not.
- Try using `self.btn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`.
- Maybe, you're re-setting the `enabled` property to `YES` somewhere later in the code.

These points were all I could think of, tell me if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xib file to build interface. Then make sure that IBOutlet is set for self.btn? If not, Then set IBOutlet for that. If you post your full source code for self.btn, Then i can help you more.